# PHP unserialize - error at index

Tags: php, serialization, fuelphp

I am having some difficulties with PHP `serialize` and `unserialize` functions. I am inserting array into MySQL DB with `serialize(array)`. This is my value in DB

```
a:4:{i:0;s:29:"k44L1b_bisnode.com.xlarge.png";i:1;s:28:"q44L1b_bisnode.com.large.png";i:2;s:29:"q44L1b_bisnode.com.medium.png";i:3;s:28:"q44L1b_bisnode.com.small.png";}
```

If I do something like this

```
$images = unserialize( $apartment->images );
```

I will get error: `ErrorException [ Notice ]: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 9 of 208 bytes`. `$apartment` is my DB ORM object and if I do something like `echo $apartment->images` it will output me the above serialized string.

But if I do something like this

```
$images = unserialize( 'a:4:{i:0;s:29:"k44L1b_bisnode.com.xlarge.png";i:1;s:28:"q44L1b_bisnode.com.large.png";i:2;s:29:"q44L1b_bisnode.com.medium.png";i:3;s:28:"q44L1b_bisnode.com.small.png";}' );
```

It will work... Huh? var_dump() of $apartment->images returns

```
string(208) "a:4:{i:0;s:29:"k44L1b_bisnode.com.xlarge.png";i:1;s:28:"q44L1b_bisnode.com.large.png";i:2;s:29:"q44L1b_bisnode.com.medium.png";i:3;s:28:"q44L1b_bisnode.com.small.png";}"
```

Comment: Please post `var_dump($apartment->images);`

Comment: I have edit my original post and added var_dump($apartment->images);

Comment: I tried that, but I get the same error.

Comment: The `var_dump` claims 208 characters, I count 169.... Whats up, you are not looking at it in a browser are you?

Comment: What character encodings are you using? Could you also post     `var_dump((int)substr($apartment->images,9,1))` ?

Comment: I think Wrikken's on to something here. I only get 168.

Comment: Aha, do not store it html-encoded.... `unserialize(html_entity_decode($apartment->images, ENT_QUOTES));`

Comment: Huh? The serialized string in DB is 168 characters you are right. I have no clues why var_dump() says it is 208...?

Comment: Wrikken's right. Your string run through `htmlspecialchars` comes to exactly 208 characters. Is your ORM (or somewhere else) encoding it for convenience or something?

Comment: `unserialize(html_entity_decode($apartment->images, ENT_QUOTES))` this solved the problem. I have no clues why it stores it as html-encoded.

Comment: Wrikken, please turn your comment into an answer so we can upvote it and Primoz can checkmark it.

Comment: @Wrikken can you turn you comment into answer so I can checkmark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guy from FuelPHP noted on this http://docs.fuelphp.com/general/views.html#/security so this was my issue.

**Security**
*By default, Views use output encoding to sanitize anything you pass to them using Security::htmlentities(). If you want to pass something unfiltered, you can use the method set($name, $value, false).*